# Tubing connector identification request

Tags: cell-culture

this may not be on topic but I'm hoping someone here can tell me the name/manufacturer of the connectors used with the thin teflon tubing in this picture:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try looking for "Luer valves" or "Luer fittings".

For instance, we buy this kind of supplies [from WPI](http://www.wpi-europe.com/en/products/laboratory_supplies/luervalve.shtml).

Comment: Thanks, but I don't believe these are Luer fittings - as I understand it they are some type of compression fitting, you can push the teflon tubing through to the desired length, then screw tighten the fitting to seal it in place.

Comment: @zephyr: aren't those the ones on the bottom right of the link in the answer (not sure)?

Comment: hmm not sure, they do look similar. Looking at the kit contents link though I don't see anything that sounds right.

Comment: I think this is what I'm looking for: http://www.westernanalytical.com/pdf/VLp5-8.pdf